# Binding in xaml with with tags/elements rather than attributes?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this code:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding TopMenu.MenuItems}">
</Menu>
```

This works as expected. However, I want to define ItemsSource as a sub element of `Menu`, rather than as an attribute. I tried this:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemsSource>{Binding TopMenu.MenuItems}</Menu.ItemsSource>
</Menu>
```

but it does not appear to be valid.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**

I want to do this to help lay out my documents better. For instance, I have elements with many attributes like this:

```
<ListView  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxInnerGroupStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          Visibility="{Binding Visible,
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
           PreviewMouseWheel="ChildListView_PreviewMouseWheel">
```

With all the attributes that `ListView` has, it's hard to layout the document so as to avoid very long, hard to read lines. Particularly the large `Visibility` attribute is hard to format. Therefore, I want to change large attributes like this to child elements. For the above example, I think this is easier to read:

```
<ListView  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxInnerGroupStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
           PreviewMouseWheel="ChildListView_PreviewMouseWheel">
    <ListView.Visibility>
        {Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}
    </ListView.Visibility>
```

Comment: In general I'm having a lot of trouble working with xaml. I like it better than winforms, but it could be a lot more intuitive.

Comment: First of all it'd be nice to understand why do you want to do that.

Comment: Try <Binding Path="TopMenu.MenuItems"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Markup Extensions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (such as [`System.Windows.Data.Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) have the ability to *"provide a Value"*, which is simply an instance of an object that is then added to the object graph, or treated in different ways by the XAML processor.

This means, in short, that the syntax:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding TopMenu.MenuItems}"/>
```

is translated by the XAML processor to something like this:

```
var menu = new Menu();
menu.ItemsSource = new Binding{Path = "TopMenu.MenuItems"});
```

of course the above isn't exactly what happens, since the `Binding` MarkupExtension specifies otherwise, but you get the idea.

if you were to create an XAML representation of the above object graph defined in C# code, that would be:

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.ItemsSource>
     <Binding Path="TopMenu.MenuItems"/>
  </Menu.ItemsSource>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the question to indicate a justification for all this. Your solution will, unfortunately, still end up being a bit verbose - I hope future versions of xaml/wpf improve this area.

Comment: @Oliver if you're having troubles with `Visibility`, in particular, see [Combining MarkupExtension and IValueConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35416/Use-of-MarkupExtension-with-Converters-in-WPF). You could create your own `BoolToVisibilityConverter` which can be used with a markupextension syntax and avoid the need for `StaticResource` (something like `Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={my:BoolToVisibility}}"/>`

Comment: @Oliver still, I believe that proper indentation and vertical placement of XAML attributes make a much more elegant code than having individual properties defined as sub-elements of the main UI element.